# make characters bold based on conditionals using xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I have a pandas dataframe that looks as shown in the screenshot. I want to apply conditional formatting using xlsxwriter to make the values of column "C" bold if column "B" value is "Total".
The below code doesnot seem to work

```
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
l = ['C3:C500']
for columns in l:
    worksheet.conditional_format(columns, {'type': 'text',
                                          'criteria': 'containing',
                                           'value':     'Total',
                                           'font_color': "gray"})
```

[image]

Here is my updated code:

```
l = ['C3:C500']
for columns in l:
    worksheet.conditional_format(columns, {'type': 'formula',
                                           'criteria': '=$B3="Total"',
                                           'format': bold})
    worksheet.conditional_format(columns, {'type': 'formula',
                                           'criteria': '=$B3!="Total"',
                                           'font_color': "gray"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to using conditional formats in XlsxWriter is to figure out what you want to do in Excel first.

In this case if you want to format a cell based on the value in another cell you need to use the "formula" conditional format type. You also need to make sure that you get the range and absolute values (the ones with $ signs) correct.

Here is a working example based on your code:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('conditional_format.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('B3', 'Total')
worksheet.write('B4', 'Foo')
worksheet.write('B5', 'Bar')
worksheet.write('B6', 'Total')

worksheet.write('C3', 'Yes')
worksheet.write('C4', 'Yes')
worksheet.write('C5', 'Yes')
worksheet.write('C6', 'Yes')

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
l = ['C3:C500']
for columns in l:
    worksheet.conditional_format(columns, {'type': 'formula',
                                           'criteria': '=$B3="Total"',
                                           'format': bold})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The above code bolds characters for column C if the column C value is "Total" whereas I want to bold characters for column C if the value of column B is "Total"

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your update/clarification.

Comment: I have a following question on this. Along with bolding the characters for Total, I want to color the characters of column C with gray for non total values in column B

Comment: I tried the above code(attached in the question) based on the solution you provided but it doesnot colour any character in Column C

Comment: In that case you need to add a second conditional format with a formula like `=$B3<>"Total"` and a different (gray) format.

Comment: The screenshot clearly shows that it does work. No? Are you using Excel or some other application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190376/discussion-between-jmcnamara-and-shanoo).